# why can't get expected result after truthy switch statements?

Tags: javascript

Trying to find all divisible numbers of an integer but getting an incorrect answer after switch loop.

```
function divisors(integer) {

  let divNumbers = []

  switch(true) {
    case (integer % 2 === 0):
      divNumbers.push(2);

    case (integer % 3 === 0):
      divNumbers.push(3);

    case (integer % 4 === 0):
      divNumbers.push(4);


    case (integer % 5 === 0):
      divNumbers.push(5);

      break;

    default: divNumbers.push(integer)
  }

  return divNumbers; 
};

divisors(15)
```

Getting 3, 4, 5 as divNumbers where 4 shouldn't be here. Why?

Comment: Because switch cases *fall through* by default. The other conditions are not checked. Think of `case` as an entry point in a series of statements. All statements that come after the first `case` that matches will be executed.

Comment: but if I put `break` after 1st case it stops just there.

Comment: Yes, that's how `break` works.

Comment: but I want it to go through all cases and `divNumbers` to collect all numbers that match. How do I change my code?

Comment: Make every `case` an `if` statement instead (and remove the outer `switch` of course).

Comment: see my answer. there's a complete solution for any number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the correct solution that will not be hardcoded:

```
var divisors  = function (num) { 
    const initial = num, result=[]; 
    while(num--) { 
       if (initial % num ===0) { 
           result.push(num); 
       } 
    } 
    return result; 
}
```

If you want to get the number itself in divisors, do this:

```
var divisors  = function (num) { 
    const initial = num, result=[]; 
    num++;
    while(num--) { 
       if (initial % num ===0) { 
           result.push(num); 
       } 
    } 
    return result; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Switch stamenets fall through by default. To prevent this, you should `break` after each one. Having said that, you'll only end up with `3` in that case, as `15` is divisible by `3`. Once the division was successful, you'd `break` out of the switch:

```js
function divisors(integer) {

  let divNumbers = []

  switch (true) {
    case (integer % 2 === 0):
      divNumbers.push(2);
      break;

    case (integer % 3 === 0):
      divNumbers.push(3);
      break;

    case (integer % 4 === 0):
      divNumbers.push(4);
      break;

    case (integer % 5 === 0):
      divNumbers.push(5);
      break;

    default:
      divNumbers.push(integer)
  }

  return divNumbers;
};

console.log(divisors(15));
```

To ensure that you end up with both `3` and `5` in the array, I'd recommend swapping to `if` conditionals instead, because you want **multiple** conditions to trigger:

```js
function divisors(integer) {
  let divNumbers = []

  if (integer % 2 === 0) {
    divNumbers.push(2);
  }

  if (integer % 3 === 0) {
    divNumbers.push(3);
  }

  if (integer % 4 === 0) {
    divNumbers.push(4);
  }

  if (integer % 5 === 0) {
    divNumbers.push(5);
  }
  
  return divNumbers;
}

console.log(divisors(15));
```

Hope this helps! :)